# how to force a filter() to match exact cases (case sensitivity) in sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, filter, sqlalchemy, case-sensitive

I am using sqlalchemy with mysql database. When I am using following query on User object :

```
session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'admin').all()
```

I get all the results which have usename as 'Admin', 'admin', 'ADMIN' (basically all case-insensitive 'admin'). I would like to know how can I force a filter() to filter exact matches (without ignoring cases)?

Update : Actually I just came to know that mysql does not allow case-sensitive columns for varchar() datatype. So the simplest solution would be to force a column to be case-sensitive while declaring in mysql, as :

```
  `name` VARCHAR(255) BINARY NULL UNIQUE,
```

But I would still love to know how can I force a filter to match the results exactly (not ignoring cases). Is there anyway using some inbuilt (or custom, if possible) sqlalchemy func?

Comment: Don't know MySQL, but why don't you give `cast` a try. I am not sure how well does SA support this for MySQL thougth: `session.query(User).filter(cast(User.name, VARCHAR(255, binary=True)) == 'admin').all()`

Answer (score 13):

```
select * from users where binary name = 'AdMin';
select * from users where binary name = 'admin';


from sqlalchemy import func
User.query.filter(User.name == func.binary('AdMin')).count()
User.query.filter(User.name == func.binary('admin')).count()
```

Comment: great!! but... HOW DID YOU FIGURED OUT? I can't find nothing about "func" on the SQLAlchemy website :(

Comment: func allows you to pass database specific functions into a query. I believe you lose some of the purpose of an ORM by doing this as calling something like func.count() may not be portable to all database engines. `from sqlalchemy.sql import func` More info here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html

Comment: A comment was falsely added [as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77492953/5211833): "So, `func.binary` is not portable everywhere. For example, it does not work with `sqlite3` engine."

Answer (score 1):

Generally, what SQLAlchemy does is construct a SQL string query out of the expressions. Typing freely your above expression would yield something like this:

```
SELECT user.* FROM user WHERE user.name = 'admin'
```

Of course, `user.*` would replaced by an explicity enumeration of all `user` columns.

The thing is that it depends what this query returns: If it compares case-insensitively, there is not much SQLAlchemy can do. From what I gather looking around, you can explicitly construct a query using `WHERE BINARY user.name = 'admin'`. However, I am not aware of a SQLAlchemy equivalent, so you might be stuck with building a literal string here.

Anyways, I would suggest that you ask on the SQLAlchemy list for the particular solution (especially, I think it would be interesting to know a way of intergrating the `BINARY` into a `WHERE` query).